# Why is my jquery ajax giving a 406

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, spring

What is causing this error? I believe it is an incorrect accept header.  Shouldn't the jquery ajax method set that to the correct value when datatype: 'json'?

406 Not Acceptable

Here's my Spring Controller mapping:

```
    @RequestMapping(value={"/{ID}"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Double getRating(@PathVariable(value="ID") final Long id, 
        @RequestParam Long rating) {
    Double ratingResult = rate.get_rating(id);
    return ratingResult;
}
```

Here's my javascript:

```
    $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: '/ratings/' + ID + '?rating=' + rating,
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        var ratingResult = obj.ratingResult;
    });
```

My accept header value is */*

Comment: Check your capitalization -- `dataType`, not `datatype`. And, normally, jQuery uses an `Accepts` of [`'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/ajax.js#L324) for JSON requests (at least, in 1.6.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify the server side:

But if you have incorrect response content type it supposed to be application/json, remember what you need to add jackson to your /lib directory.

In your serlvet-name.xml file.
And please use firebug to see the json notation if you can catch the object response in your console.

Please verify the client side:

Examine your request headers:

```
...
dataType: 'json',
...
```

Accept  */*
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
This will explicitly tell the server side that you are expecting JSON.

And... check this: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try with 'text/json'...

Comment: that gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

set you `dataType` to `json` and you dont need to do `$.parseJSON` jquery will parse it for you

```
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url: '/ratings/' + ID + '?rating=' + rating,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){

    var ratingResult = data.ratingResult;
    //or sometimes you have to do data[0]
    var ratingresult = data[0].ratingResult;
});
```