# Not acceptable error when Making JQuery POst

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a script making ajax call as described below.

```
$.ajax({

     url: 'internal/something.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: { TabsObj: JSON.stringify(Tabs) },
     dataType: "text",
     accept : {text: "text/plain"},
     success: function(data,status,he)
     {
          alert(data);
          window.onbeforeunload = null;
          window.location = "somewhere.php";
     }}).fail(
              function(msg) 
              { 
                  alert(msg.responseText+" Error In Connection, Try Again...");
                  window.onbeforeunload = null;
                  window.location = "confirmTest.php"; 
              });
```

But each time this request is made, I always Recieve this error message

```
406 Not Acceptable
```

An appropriate representation of the requested resource `/internal/timeUp.php` could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not `Found\nerror` was encountered while trying to use an `ErrorDocument` to handle the request.

Any help on this will really be appreciated.

Comment: If the Web server detects that the data it wants to return is not acceptable to the client, it returns a header containing the 406 error code.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the client side:

Examine your request headers:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Accept / Accept: application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01 This will explicitly tell the server side that you are expecting JSON.

And... check this: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html

courtesy: [Why is my jquery ajax giving a 406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219289/why-is-my-jquery-ajax-giving-a-406)